# LLBLGEN select where

Tags: c#, sql, llblgen

I had generated an entity who is ClientEntity from a table of my database.
My table Client had 3 columns : 
-ClientId (int)
-IsValited (bit)
-CreatedOn (datetime)

I want to create llblgen sqlquery with predicate filters :

```
select ClientId , IsValited ,IsValited 
from Client
where (ClientId = 1 and IsValited=1) or
      (ClientId = 2 and IsValited=1) or
      (ClientId = 3 and IsValited=1)
```

Ideally i want generate dynamically (ClientId = x and IsValited=y) in my llblgen sqlquery.

Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
List<EzClientEntity> listClient = getClientToSet();
EzClientCollection colSel = new EzClientCollection ();
                IPredicateExpression filtersSel = new PredicateExpression();
                listClient.ForEach(o => filtersSel.AddWithOr((EzClientFields.ClientId  == o.ClientId ) & (EzClientFields.IsValited== o.IsValited )));
                colSel.GetMulti(filtersSel);
```